# Why does @available (iOS, unavailable ...) won't work?

Tags: swift, xcode, sdk, ibm-cloud

When trying to compile https://github.com/IBM/swift-sdk-core following error will be thrown:

*'init(fileURLWithPath:relativeTo:)' is only available in iOS 9.0 or newer*

at Line 61 in **Sources/IBMSwiftSDKCore/CredentialUtils.swift**

even though *@available (iOS, unavailable, message: "ConfigBasedAuthenticatorFactory is currently available on Linux only.")* is defined at top of Credentials struct.

XCode-Version: Version 11.4 (11E146)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the deployment target set to?

Comment: I cloned the SwiftPackage from link (see above). You can find the manifest file here: https://github.com/IBM/swift-sdk-core/blob/master/Package.swift

Comment: I meant the Xcode deployment target.  The available's in CredentialUtils.swift are a bit odd since it's got an available for iOS 9 within the CredentialUtils structure and the available(iOS, unavailable, ...) outside.  I was wondering if having a deployment target of something less than iOS 9 might get the compiler into a slightly confused state where an attempt to reference the credentials structure could give the iOS 9 error message instead of the not-in-iOS-at-all message.

Comment: I could fix this problem by adding platform specifications to swift package file:  platforms: [
           .macOS(.v10_12),
           .iOS(.v10),
           .tvOS(.v10),
           .watchOS(.v3)
       ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this problem by adding platform specifications to swift package file:

platforms: [
           .macOS(.v10_12),
           .iOS(.v10),
           .tvOS(.v10),
           .watchOS(.v3)
       ],

Answer (score 0):

We can install the `IBM Swift SDK Core` using the Cocoapods,

```
pod 'IBMSwiftSDKCore','1.0.0'
```

Deployment Target used is  **13.2**